# Graphing when value changes with if/then formula in Excel

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

I have a list of ticket numbers, with submit dates and completed dates. Our ticket system is crap, so these are the only dates recorded against any particular ticket.

My boss wants a graph that has time on the X-axis, and a count of how many tickets were open on any particular date.

Let's say the date range is from `1/1/2014 - 1/7/2014`.

I want to be able to point at a date and determine if a ticket was open, closed or non-existent on that date.

I thought this formula might do it, if `U1` referred to a date range, the X axis:

```
=IF($F2>=$U$1,"",(IF($G2<=$U$1,"closed","open")))
```

[image]

(please see the image; I haven't got rep to post images yet)

I don't have the knowledge to go beyond this though. Is there a formula or script or something I can use so I don't have to make a massive array to create this graph?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You have three distinct requirements:

## 1 **a graph that has time on the X-axis**

Select ColumnsU:V after population as #2 below and insert a chart. With a Scatter this might look so:

[image: SO24542928 example]

## 2 **count of how many tickets were open on any  particular date**

Since you are prepared to restrict this to about half a year I suggest "biting the bullet" and nothing fancy:

in U2: `1/1/14`
in V2: `=IF(F2>T$1,"non-existent",IF(AND(F2<=T$1,G2>=T$1),"open","closed"))`

and both copied down as far as 1/7/2014.

## 3  **point at a date and determine if a ticket was open, closed or non-existent on that date**

If your "date pointer" is a value in T1, then in T2 and copied down:

```
=IF(F2>T$1,"non-existent",IF(AND(F2<=T$1,G2>=T$1),"open","closed"))
```